# powershell string comparison operators ignoring wildcards

Tags: regex, powershell, substring, wildcard

I am trying to compare strings like this:

```
'Backup Exec Alert: Job Success (Server: "AMSMGMT") (Job: "Ams-Daily-Back")' -match '(Server: "AMSMGMT") (Job: "Ams-Daily-Back")'
```

Which is returning false because I need to scape the wildcards e.g.

```
'/(Server: "AMSMGMT"/) /(Job: "Ams-Daily-Back"/)'
```

Question:

Is there any powershell function to find substrings ignoring wildcards/regex?

thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're doing a literal string match, -like might be a better choice than -match

```
'Backup Exec Alert: Job Success (Server: "AMSMGMT") (Job: "Ams-Daily-Back")' -like '*(Server: "AMSMGMT") (Job: "Ams-Daily-Back")'

True
```

Comment: thank you very much mjolinor, this is what I was after

Answer (score 0):

As previous answer, like is more appropriate but you could also use "Escape"

```
'Backup Exec Alert: Job Success (Server: "AMSMGMT") (Job: "Ams-Daily-Back")' -match [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Escape('(Server: "AMSMGMT") (Job: "Ams-Daily-Back")')
```

Or C# contains method

```
'Backup Exec Alert: Job Success (Server: "AMSMGMT") (Job: "Ams-Daily-Back")'.Contains('(Server: "AMSMGMT") (Job: "Ams-Daily-Back")')
```